# Passing Oauth token in email attachment

Tags: email, oauth, bearer-token

We have an authentication server that generates the token.
We understand that with the token, when you make a HTTP request, you have to pass Authentication Bearer: xxxxx in the HTTP header.

Now my question is can users create an attachment with the token and send an email to the sender and then the sender extracts the token out from the attachment and validate it against the authentication server?

Thanks for your time and help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically that would be possible but without any additional measurements it is insecure and it would violate the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3, saying:

> Access token credentials (as well as any confidential access token
> attributes) MUST be kept confidential in transit and storage, and only
> shared among the authorization server, the resource servers the access
> token is valid for, and the client to whom the access token is issued.

Since e-mail goes over unprotected channels, you would have to apply some confidentiality and integrity mechanism (e.g. encrypt the e-mail/attachment) to leverage this in a secure way.